# MySQL UNION WITH CONDITION

Tags: mysql, sql

I wonder if there is a way to union a second table only when certain condition is met?

like:

```
select t_1
    (...)

if(true,
    (union select t_2),
    [do nothing])
```

Comment: union select from  t_2 where <the if-condition>

Comment: show the actual condition you want to check or we don't know what to recommend.  and for best help, show your schema and sample data and expected results for that sample data.